# Where to put commonly used methods Android

Tags: android, methods, android-activity

If I have methods that are used by most Activities, would it be better to put the methods in each Activity class or create one static class that holds the methods?  Please explain why, thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some example methods. Are they purely stateless? If so, could probably be in a static library. (Examples include things like "calculate distance")

Comment: @debracey What if they needed states?

Comment: @onepiece : As debracey stated - it would be helpful to have some examples of what your methods will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the methods are purely stateless, or if they just need a reference to something that an activity can provide (e.g., a `Context`) then it is probably easiest to just make a class full of static methods.

If the methods need to maintain some state that can't be encapsulated in the methods as they are executing, it is probably best to make a regular class because it is generally considered bad to use static variables for the purposes of maintaining state -- as this can lead to trouble with multi-threaded applications.

If you go the class route, the activities/etc that need to make use of these methods can create an object of the type you define, then make use of its `public` methods.

There are a whole hose of other options -- one that is also relatively common is to create a Singleton that all activities can access without needing to create their own instances of your class. Singletons are often used for management classes -- cases where you only need one instance at any time and that instance is geared to provide event callbacks when things occur.

The choice is really up to you. Without knowing what it is you want to accomplish, it is hard to recommend a 'best' option.

Comment: Is creating a regular class essentially the same thing as copy and pasting the method into every Activity?  And sorry for not providing examples, I only have ideas not the actual code yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by copying and pasting. You'd create an instance of the object where you need it and access the method

Comment: I mean copy and pasting as in putting all the methods in each Activity class so you can directly call them without creating an object instance.